# Raspberry pi - run a python script through apache server

Tags: php, python, apache, cgi, raspberry-pi

I am trying to come up with a way to run a python file on my raspberry pi through apache.

To run the program in ssh i type `sudo python testfile.py`
I have tried through php using `exec('sudo python /home/pi/python/testfile.py')`

but no joy, i get an error in my `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
 PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/index2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/$
```

I have tried using cgi also. but get this error :

```
(13)Permission denied: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/runpython.cgi' failed
Premature end of script headers: runpython.cgi
```

I have googled as much as I can, and checked here to see if I could find anything.

Can anyone offer some help/advice ? Thanks

Comment: Does the user running Apache have rights to execute your `runpython.cgi`? Do you have CGI enabled? Does the user running Apache have the right to use `sudo`? (By the way, don't do that.) What about this `/var/www/index2.php`? Anything important there? What is that Python script? Are you trying to build a web application backed by Python or is it a shell script that you wish to execute via a web interface?

Comment: It is almost certainly related to the use of `sudo`. When you execute the program (with `sudo`) through the shell, you have to type in the password, right? How is the Apache user (probably `www-data`) going to do that? There are ways around this, but you're going to be opening up a can of worms related to security.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at mod_wsgi: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

Also, are you sure your script needs to run as root?